# Concatenate many rows into one

Tags: sql-server

I have a relational table:

```
EmployeeOptionRelation
EmployeeId    OptionId
1             3
1             4
1             5
```

then I have Option table:

```
Option
OptionId    Name
3           A
4           B
5           C
```

I need to have a result like this

```
EmployeeId Name
1          A,B,C
```

I did something like this but doesn't work because is telling me that column OptionId needs to be part of the group by, I have an idea how to do it but I don't want to repeat same queries one in the main one and the other inside the STUFF

```
SELECT em.EmployeeId,
       STUFF(
            (   
                SELECT '; ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, o.Name)
                    FROM [Option] o
                    WHERE o.OptionId = em.OptionId
                    FOR XML PATH, TYPE
            ).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')          
            , 1
            , 1
            , ''
    )
 FROM [EmployeeOptionRelation] em
 GROUP BY em.EmployeeId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually made it like this:

```
; with A 
as
(
SELECT distinct em.EmployeeId,
   (
        SELECT o.Name + ','  as 'data()'
            FROM [Option] O
            inner join [EmployeeOptionRelation] EM2
                on o.OptionId = EM2.OptionId
            where
                EM2.EmployeeId = EM.EmployeeId
            FOR XML PATH('')
) as Name
 FROM [EmployeeOptionRelation] em
)
select 
    EmployeeId
    , Name = left(Name, len(Name) - 1) 
from A
```